# WebStorm: How to debug a project in Grunt.js configuration?

Tags: gruntjs, webstorm

I use WebStorm to write a web project runned by Grunt.js.

[image]

My problem is that I can't debug the project. If I put breakpoints and run it in debug mode, WebStorm ignores the breakpoints.

Do you know how it's possible to debug a Grunt project?

Comment: sure it's possible. What are you trying to debug? grunt tasks? Child processes spawned by Grunt? Or?